# GNOME : Ubuntu 18.04 ALT+TAB delay

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

How to remove any delay between pressing alt+tab and switcher emergence in Ubuntu 18.04 [GNOME 3]?

Comment: Delay is intentional. So when you quick switch to previous app, it's don't need to show the switching window at all.

Comment: @shantanu I don't think so. delay is painful for me. I would like to know which windows I am switching to, and I want to see its icon AT ONCE when I press `alt + tab`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved it by simply installing https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1317/alt-tab-switcher-popup-delay-removal/

P.s. it remains to solve [Ubuntu 18.04 super key switcher (gnome-shell app menu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033731/ubuntu-18-04-super-key-switcher-gnome-shell-app-menu) and i can switch from unity to gnome ^)

Comment: How to install it? It downloads a js and json file.

Comment: @relG I do not remember all the details, but probably gnome extensions are not enabled by default in Ubuntu.
You should install the gnome-tweaks package and also go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local and follow instructions to enable them. 

After that, going to the provided link will show you a button to enable/disable the specific extension. That works pretty well :)

Comment: Works like magic. Thank you! But is there a trade-off?

Comment: For those who have problems with one browser, remember that you have more than one. I was sticking to Google Chrome but it wasn't letting me use Extensions. I switched to Firefox and I solved it in no time..

Comment: Seems you have to install this plugin via ubuntu's "software center", means, you start the "software center", then search "alt tab switcher removal" , then this plugin is shown and you click "install"

Answer (score 5):

Stolen shamelessly from here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/08/speed-up-alt-tab-ubuntu-18-04/

- open Ubuntu Software app
- search for the string "remove alt tab popup"
- install the `Alt-Tab Switcher Popup Delay Removal` app

Comment: thank you so much!  `delay` is painful to me!

Comment: can not find this app in my ubuntu 18.04