# Ubuntu 18.04 super key switcher (gnome-shell app menu)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 18.04, gnome-shell

I notice that there is a tiny delay between pressing super key and app menu emergence. Is there a way to reduce it to zero ms ?

Moreover it is very uncomfortable, that keyboard arrow keys focus is missing when the menu appears (so need to press multiple times arrow keys to catch focus). Is there any workarounds for this ? Some tweaks maybe ?

Thanks is advance!

**UPDATE**

Need to notice, that <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> switcher and super-key app preview switcher is a different presentations.

**UPDATE**

I tried https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/ but it didn't helped to solve the problem. Maybe due to already usage of gnome-tweak-tool - animation off. I'm still in search - how to completely remove  any animations and delays from gnome-shell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNOME : Ubuntu 18.04 ALT+TAB delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033723/gnome-ubuntu-18-04-alttab-delay)

Comment: not a diplicate at all,  question has been updated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: I noticed that when using Win+S combination - delay looks to be subjectively smaller. So the delay we facing here is probably have something to do with the `SUPER` key handling in Ubuntu/Gnome. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04