# Make Alt + Tab behavior in Ubuntu 18.04 same as in Ubuntu 16

Tags: gnome-shell, application-switcher

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 18.04. The <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior has changed. I already installed a gnome extension to remove the delay as recommended in this answer: [GNOME : Ubuntu 18.04 ALT+TAB delay](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033723/gnome-ubuntu-18-04-alttab-delay), but this still does require an extra press on <kbd>Tab</kbd> to actually switch the window. I find it very annoying.

Comment: Just a point: even the behavior in 16.04 has already been terrible and so bugged that it's hard to describe, what the intended behavior was just by observation.